# React Native Image Binding

Tags: javascript, react-native

Trying to navigate some React Native image bindings which I am unsure how to proceed.

Right now, the following code works.

I have a data file of items:

MyData.js

```
import { Images } from '@configuration';

const myData = [
  {
    name: 'One',
    img: Images.one
  },
  {
    name: 'Two',
    img: Images.two
  },
  {
    name: 'Three',
    img: Images.three
  }
]
```

And the images.js file

```
export const Images = {
  one: require('@assets/images/one.png'),
  two: require('@assets/images/two.png'),
  three: require('@assets/images/three.png')
}
```

And in my React screen, I am trying to render that as:

```
import {MyData} from '@data';

export default function MyScreen({navigation}) {
  const [myData] = useState(MyData);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList data={myData} keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
                  renderItem={({item, index}) => (
        <Card image={item.img}>
        </Card>
       )}
      </>
    </View>
  )
}
```

The above displays the image accordingly.

Now, I wanted to have the data binding of the FlatList bound to an API which returns the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    name: "One",
    img: "Images.one"
  },
  {
    name: "Two",
    img: "Images.two"
  },
  {
    name: "Three",
    img: "Images.three"
  }
]
```

Of course the binding to the Card image does not work as the img is interpreted as a string.

I tried to modify the image binding to:

```
<Card image={JSON.parse(item.img)}>
</Card>
```

But this simply throw an error and the image does not render.

Simply stumped on how images would be handled in this scenario.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this Images always have three fixed items as one,two,three? Will be there any four I mean?

Comment: I have a lot of images. I shortened things for brevity. And the images are not all numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do some adjustment in your json, it is possible

Just keep image name inside json data

```
  {
    name: "One",
    img: "one"
  },
  {
    name: "Two",
    img: "two"
  },
  {
    name: "Three",
    img: "three"
  }
]
```

and when you want to render it you can use

```
import { Images } from '@configuration';

<Card image={Images[item.img]}>
</Card>
```

Comment: The value I am getting for this code `{Images[item.img]}` is blank. I am unsure why, when there is a corresponding value for the item.img on the images.js file. Am I missing something? I do have the import also declared. I also made the json data adjustments.

Comment: Figured it out. Data I have was not committed on the database. Working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your name property is always same as the actual image source, then I would consider using name property to extract image url like below:

```
import { Images } from '@configuration';

<Card image={Images[item.name.toLowerCase()]}>
</Card>
```